# How can i Confirm request to friend?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I`m developing android application.I get requests friends from me/friendrequests .
How can i Confirm request to friend ???

```
asyncRanFace.request("me/friendrequests",new RequestListener(){

                            public void onComplete(String res, Object state) {
                                try{
                                    JSONObject jsonRequest = Util.parseJson(res);
                                    JSONArray friendsRequestArray =  jsonRequest.getJSONArray("data");                                   
                                    JSONObject friendRequest;
                                    String fRId=null,fRNm= null;
                                    for(int i =0 ; i<friendsRequestArray.length(); i++){
                                        friendRequest= friendsRequestArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                        JSONObject temp= friendRequest.getJSONObject("from");

                                        fRId = temp.getString("id");
                                        fRNm= temp.getString("name");
                                        myRequestFriendsMap.put(fRId, fRNm);

                                    }


                        }
```

Comment: asyncRanFace.request("me/friendrequests",new RequestListener()

Comment: yes and now i whant confirm request from friend!

Comment: ok, sorry, not much idea about facebook liking.

Comment: you may visit developer.facebook.com for more information, it might help you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot 'accept' a user's friend requests, you can only use the API to see what the outstanding Friend Requests are. It's a security measure so unwanted Friends are not added automatically by malicious applications.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#friendrequests

Only a `GET` call is allowed. `POST` and `DELETE` calls, to accept or delete, respectively, are not allowed.